# Equivalent of hosts file in proper DNS server in Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

In my hosts file %systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts I can have entries `portfolio.local 192.168.4.175`

Is it possible to have idrac.example.com point to an internal ip but have it  on the server 2008 r2 box doing our routing so it's network wide

Answer (score 3):

Yes with a DNS server.

You create a DNS A record pointing to the correct IP, and its done network wide.